# Is it bad to have more than two Timers running in a Cocos2D project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Is it bad to have more than one CCTimer running? The most I've ever seen is two, and I'm wondering if it's bad practice to have more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many CCTimer or scheduled selectors `[self schedule:@selector(callMe:)]` running as you want.

Ultimately performance and/or memory usage depend a whole lot more on the code that is performed in a scheduled selector, rather than scheduling itself.

But it's true, most classes in a Cocos2D project get along fine with just one scheduled update method. That's why most of them simply use: `[self scheduleUpdate];`

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that you can't use more than one CCTime or CCTimer, assuming you are being responsible about memory management. Of course, having too many can take more memory than you would like, but the exact number for "too many" depends mostly on your apps' user of memory.

Hope that helps.